# not sure what is wrong here

Tags: python, dice

Need to ask user if they want to start, end up getting input expected at most 1 arguments, got 3:

```
for i in range(1,5):
    Player1Points += roll()
    print('After this round ',player_1, 'you now have: ',Player1Points,' Points')
    while True:
        answer = input("Would you like to see", player_2, "'s score? yes/no")
        if answer == "no":
            print("how about now?")
        else:
            print("Okay")
        break

Player2Points += roll()
print('After this round ',player_2, 'you now have: ',Player2Points,' Points')
```

Input expected at most 1 arguments but got 3.

Comment: `answer = input("Would you like to see", player_2, "'s score? yes/no")` --> `answer = input("Would you like to see {}'s score? yes/no".format(player_2))`. `input` doesn't work like `print`, you need the string as a single argument, not separated by `,`

Answer (score 4):

You need to concatenate the string not use commas like a print function. Use

```
answer = input("Would you like to see" + player_2 + "'s score? yes/no")
```

instead. Or if you're using python 3.5+

```
answer = input(f"Would you like to see {player_2}'s score? yes/no")
```